# How to transfer NFTs from Solana Wallet programmatically

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft

Hey Solana enthusiasts,

I am working on Solana powered NFT project, I am using the lazy minting method but I am stuck. I want to send freshly minted NFT to a wallet address. Solana is not well documented like ethereum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want a combination of two things to properly transfer an NFT:

- create the recipient's token account: https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#associated-token-account-ata
- transfer the token to that new account: https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#transfer-token